# Move SharePoint main menu bar to be underneath banner

Tags: 2013, branding

I have designed a custom navigation menu using the term store functionality. Then I have added a banner using the `s4` tag on my css file.

Now I want to move my menu to be underneath the bannet. How can I go about this?

Comment: Pretty hard to get the complete image of what you are trying to achieve, but seems like you could handle this with some .css positioning. The custom navigation menu might need some extra space around it, so content areas etc. might have to be re-styled too.

Comment: how to use css to get this done?

Comment: Simpliest way would be to use custom .css-file, apply a `position: fixed;` to your menu and align it with `left: 50px;` or such properties. That's just the simpliest way, but as I haven't got more specific information this is all I can give.

Comment: Basically, what i have is a managed menu created from term store then on my custom css i inserted a banner at the top. my problem is that the menu is sitting ontop of the banner. i want to have the banner at the top and my menu below it.

Comment: i used this script : #DeltaTopNavigation
{
 left:30%;
 margin:0px 0 0 -150px;
 position:absolute;
}
to centre and it works, but now i want to drag it down,which tag must i addd to position it down?

Comment: Have you tried adding some top margin? You could change your `margin: 0px 0 0 -150px;` to `margin: 50px 0 0 -150px` for example.

Comment: Thank you Moe, thats what i was missing. i really appreciate it.